# Spending Limite Azure Resource Groups

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

When I divide my subscriptions with resources, is possible to set the spend limit by resource group?

Example:

1. Subscription 1 - 500 USD

   - Resource Group 1 - 100 USD
   - Resource Group 2 - 400 USD

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, it is not possible to set the spending limit by resource groups.

You may leave your feedback here.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170030-signup-and-billing

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

**OR**

**Add tags to your resources to group your billing data:**

You can use tags to group billing data for supported services. For example, if you run several VMs for different teams, then you can use tags to categorize costs by cost center (HR, marketing, finance) or environment (production, pre-production, test).

**Note:** The tags show up throughout different cost reporting views. For example, they're visible in your cost analysis view right away and detail usage .csv after your first billing period.

For more details, refer “[Ways to monitor your costs when using Azure Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-getting-started#ways-to-monitor-your-costs-when-using-azure-services)”.